# Is any smooth homeomorphism isotopic to a smooth embedding?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:D^m\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth map ($D^m$ is the unit ball).
We call $f$ embedding if it is a homeomorphism on the image and the
derivative $D_xf$ is nonsingular at each point $x\in D^m$ ($\text{
rank}(D_xf_1)=m$). We call $f$  w-embedding if it is a homeomorphism on
the image (we drop the assumption on the rank).

Is each w-embedding $f$ isotopic to an embedding? More precisely does
there exist a continuous family of w-embeddings $\{f_t\}$ from $f_0=f$ to
an embedding $f_1$?

If no, how large must be the singular set $\{x\in D^m; \text{
rank}(D_xf_1)<m\}$? Can it be made finite?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there exist such a family.

Since $f$ is a homemorphism, $\text{
rank}(D_{x_0}f_1)=m$ at some point $x_0$.

WLOG, $x_0=0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Consider the family $f_t\colon D^m\to \mathbb R^m$ defined by
$$f_t(x)=\frac{f((1-t)x)}{1-t}$$
and set
$$f_1(x)=D_0f(x).$$

Comment: This, is true. Actually, you can slightly simplify this in the following way. Take $\epsilon >0$ so that $f$ is regular in the ball of center $0$ and radius $\epsilon$. Now just put $f_t(x) = f((1-(1-\epsilon)\, t)\, x)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But is it possible to make such isotopy arbitrarily small (or constant on the boundary provided that rank=m near the boundary)? Jerzy Jezierski (user 46230).

Comment: @user46227, I think you should state it as a separate question (it is a good question, and I would like to know the answer myself).